Сборка Vim с GUI в Ubuntu с xface
Пытаюсь собрать Vim с поддержкой ГИП, но после сборки сообщает, что графический интерфейс не активирован.
Команда конфигурации:
./configure --with-features=huge --with-x --enable-gui=gtk3 --enable-fail-if-missing

Результат
checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... yes  
checking if X11 header files can be found... yes  
checking for _XdmcpAuthDoIt in -lXdmcp... yes  
checking for IceOpenConnection in -lICE... yes  
checking for XpmCreatePixmapFromData in -lXpm... no  
checking if X11 header files implicitly declare return values... no  
checking size of wchar_t... 4  
checking --enable-gui argument... GTK+ 3.x GUI support  
checking for pkg-config... no  
checking --disable-gtktest argument... gtk test enabled  
checking for X11/SM/SMlib.h... yes  
checking for X11/xpm.h... no  
checking for X11/Sunkeysym.h... yes  
checking for XIMText in X11/Xlib.h... yes  
checking for /proc link to executable... /proc/self/exe  

Но при попытке запуска, получаю сообщение
./vim -g


E25: Поддержка графического интерфейса не была активирована при компиляции

Как его заставить работать?!

Простите, а кроме конфигурирования и запуска Вы что-то еще делаете?

Ну да, после конфигурирования выполняется команда make, а уже потом проверочный запуск.

Ну да, после конфигурирования выполняется команда make, а уже потом проверочный запуск.
Команда make отрабатывает без ошибок.
Или Вы имели ввиду что‐то другое под «ещё делаете»?
Система Ubuntu LTS 22.04 установлена в ВМ, был убран предустанвленный диспетчер окон, и вместо него установлен xface.
Честно говоря, я не так чтобы очень хорошо разбирался UNIX-подобных системах. Всё, в основном, читаю, например, тот же stackjverflow.
Я догадываюсь, что ей не хватает каких‐то файлов (библиотек), но вот понять каких не могу.
Вы подскажите, какие данные Вам ещё нужно предоставить, я предоставлю

Я тоже далеко не знаток. Но, если правильно понимаю, Вы выполняете сборку vim, но не выполняете его установку. Попробуйте почитать [здесь](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/programs installation)

Не понимаю, не хочет нормально ссылку ставить....

Да, Вы правы, установку после сборки я не выполняю. Однако, это не должно влиять на возможность запуска программы. В катаолге "src/" находятся исполняемые файлы и их можно легко запситить командой, типа: ./vim или ./xxd/xxd. К тому же, например, запуск теста командой make test или конвертация PO-файлов в MO-файлы в каталоге "src/po" также не подразумевают установку программы. Для этого они используют исполняемые файлы только собранной программы в каталоге "src/". Ссылка, которую Вы указали, ведёт на страницу с альтернативными программами. Чтобы это значило?
Спасбо, что пытаетесь помочь!
